# when running hadoop fs -ls the result is "ls: Call From java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntu: ubuntu: unknown error to localhost:9000...."

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

```
ls: Call From java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntu: ubuntu: unknown error to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

My hadoop configuration is like this.

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

core-site.xml

```
<property>  
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/Public/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp</value>
<description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.permission</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9001</value>
</property>
```

Is there any question?I have been browsing the web for one whole day..help me

Comment: It seems to be saying that something is attempting to lookup "ubuntu" as a hostname, and that is failing.

Comment: @StephenC So how could I mend it?

Comment: can u put an entry something similar to {127.0.0.1    localhost   ubuntu} in your /etc/hosts file.Remove the curly brackets. I put it just for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**1.** Open `/etc/hosts` in terminal using command:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

**2.** Add this line below `127.0.0.1` line:

```
your-ip-address    hadoopmaster
```

> NOTE: To find you ip address, type this command `ifconfig | grep inet`
>   in terminal.

**3.** Change `localhost` to `hadoopmaster` in `core-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml`

**4.** Stop all hadoop processes and then start again.

Comment: Oh I had just done like this this afternoon and it worked!Anyway thanks